# Circle collider disappears after OnTriggerEnter

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection

I have a 2D circle collider with "Is Trigger" set to true. Currently, all I have it do is play an animation (on just the sprite) and set a bool when the trigger is hit:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    animator.SetBool("Touched", true);
    timerRunning = true;
}
```

This is the animation that plays when "Touched" is set to true in the animator:
[image: flower animation]

After the animation plays, the collider component seems to disappear from the game object. I want to keep it to do other stuff. Is this expected behavior? If it is, how do I keep the collider around? Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't disappear. Something else must be doing it.

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of this problem? That is, every action a reader should take, starting from a new, empty project, to create a minimal test scene that demonstrates this issue..Once we can reproduce the problem, we can test potential fixes to be sure they'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! I found the culprit. The bee (the game object the user controls) had a leftover deprecated script that destroys other colliders and I must have missed it because it had so many other components on it :D